# gsl floating point data and operations

Tags: gsl

The gsl manual only mentioned that the floating point data can be represented by "gsl_vector_float" or "gsl_matrix_float", but it doesn't provide the methods to operate on these float gsl data. It even doesn't say how to allocate memory for it, and I tried the following, which doesn't work:

```
gsl_vector_float * v = gsl_vector_alloc(100);
```

Am I missing some separate manual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The allocation API function is `gsl_vector_float_alloc`. You can check all the API function declarations for `gsl_vector_float` on  gsl_vector_float.h header (located at gsl/vector)

Comment: and if you check the header you will see that you only need to change the prefix "gsl_vector" for "gsl_vector_float" in all API calls to make it work.

Comment: Thanks! Everything is good except for gsl random generator, which seems not have a float version.